# Rails link_to if the association object is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm continually getting errors where I can't link_to an object because it is not present. Usually the object, say a 'store' has a 'customer' so on the store show page I want to link to customers that have purchased there (through a 'sale' model).

For whatever reason the customer is no longer in the database so when I am doing a `link_to warehouse.customer_id customer_path(warehouse)` I am getting a no method error on nil or `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"customers", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

Should I be doing `link_to warehouse.customer_id customer_path(warehouse) if warehouse.customer.present?` or putting an if statement around it so that I can show the customer_id instead of nothing so

```
<% if @contract.customer.present? %>
  <p><%= link_to @contract.customer_id, customer_path(@contract.customer) %>
<% else %>
  <p><%= @contract.customer_id %>
<% end %>
```

The second option looks messy and will clutter up my view but I don't want to not show the information if the object is not present :/

I also have a routing exception handler in place to redirect to root_url if the object does not exist in the database but that would mean making my link_to customer_path(warehouse.customer_id) instead of just customer_path(warehouse.customer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[link_to_if](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if) was created for cases similar to this.

```
link_to_if @contract.customer, @contract.customer_id, @contract.customer
```

Comment: Thanks Prakash. I followed your advice and was able to get this to work. I have to tweak your answer though but it was based on the information in the link. "If you are linking to the “show” path then you can just pass the object. This will force the path to not be generated until after the condition (like a hash is done)"

Comment: Careful with using `link_to_if` with a `block`. Using a block doesn't render the block regardless of if the condition is `true` or `false`.